# SELECT queries in a loop

Tags: sqlite

I am working on an sqlite3 shell.

> SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE name in ("TaskA", "TaskD") LIMIT 5;

The above statement will print the first 5 rows only. Is there a way to write this statement so the first 5 rows from each of "TaskA" and "TaskD" results are printed?

In essence, I am trying to write a loop akin to:

> FOR task in ("TaskA", "TaskD") SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE name = task LIMIT 5;

But I do not know the proper syntax.

Comment: Perhaps just `UNION`?

Comment: Hi Stansilav, I am quite new to sqlite. Could you write an elaborate command using `UNION`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY rowid) rn 
  FROM tasks 
  WHERE name IN ("TaskA", "TaskD")
)
WHERE rn <= 5
```

I used the column `rowid` to define the order of the rows.
If there is another column in your table, like a date column, that can be used to define the order, you can replace `rowid` with that column.

Comment: Thanks @forpas, it works fine! So are we appending an `rn` column on the right? I see that in the returned result (`1,2,3`):

`TaskA__99914b932b|TaskA|pnl-z840-2|1
TaskA_None_d477ee5a96|TaskA|pnl-z840-2|2
TaskA__99914b932b|TaskA|pnl-z840-2|3`


If yes, can that be omitted?

Comment: @tash Yes. Instead of `SELECT * ...` write the names of the columns that you want returned: `SELECT column1, column2, ...`